# Dictionay `__getitem__` multi-subscripting overriding

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding

I'm trying to implement a customized behavior of the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) data structure.

I want to override the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and apply some sort of regex on the value before returning it to the user.

Snippet:

```
class RegexMatchingDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, dct, regex, value_group, replace_with_group, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.replace_with_group = replace_with_group
        self.value_group = value_group
        self.regex_str = regex
        self.regex_matcher = re.compile(regex)
        self.update(dct)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value: Union[str, dict] = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        if type(value) is str:
            match = self.regex_matcher.match(value)
            if match:
                return value.replace(match.group(self.replace_with_group), os.getenv(match.group(self.value_group)))
        return value # I BELIEVE ISSUE IS HERE
```

This works perfectly for a single index level (i.e., `dict[key]`). However, when trying to multi-index it (i.e., `dict[key1][key2]`), what happens is that the first index level returns an object from my class. But, the other levels calls the default `__getitem__` in `dict`, which does not execute my customized behavior. How can I fix this?

---

An MCVE:

The aforementioned code applies a regular expression to the value and convert it to its corresponding environment variable's value if it's string (i.e., the lowest level in the dict)

```
dictionary = {"KEY": "{ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}"}

custom_dict = RegexMatchingDict(dictionary, r"((.*({(.+)}).*))", 4 ,3)
```

Let's set an env variable called `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` set to `1`.

```
import os

os.environ["ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"] = "1"
```

In this case, thie code works perfectly fine

```
custom_dict["KEY"]
```

and the returned value will be:

```
{"KEY": 1}
```

However, if we had a multi-level indexing

```
dictionary = {"KEY": {"INDEXT_KEY": "{ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}"}
custom_dict = RegexMatchingDict(dictionary, r"((.*({(.+)}).*))", 4 ,3)
custom_dict["KEY"]["INDEX_KEY"]
```

This would return

```
{ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}
```

---

P. S. There are many *similar* questions, but they all (probably) address the top-level indexing.

Comment: Could you please include an [MCVE]?

Comment: I did not want to distract people from the real issue, but okay I will.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I've added it. Check and tell me if I should do further edits.

Comment: Thanks, an [mcve] is meant to be a minimal complete and verifiable piece of code that reproduces the issue. Ideally something that one can copy/paste to find an answer to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an edit I must do ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you say yourself, is in the last line of your code.

```
if type(value) is str:
    ...
else:
    return value # I BELIEVE ISSUE IS HERE
```

This is returning a `dict`. But you want to return a `RegexMatchingDict` instead, that will know how to handle the second level of indexing. So instead of returning `value` if it is a `dict`, convert it to a `RegexMatchingDict` and return that instead. Then when `__getitem__()` is called to perform the second level of indexing, you will get your version and not the standard one.

Something like this:

```
return RegexMatchingDict(value, self.regex_str, self.value_group, self.replace_with_group)
```

This copies the other arguments from the first level since it is hard to see how the second level could be different.

Comment: I'm trying to. But, I seem to be missing how do I properly return `RegexMatchingDict` object.

Comment: I've done an edit to answer your question about conversion, but I suspect that subclassing a built-in like `dict` in this way is likely to turn out to be very much more work than you expect.

Comment: Returning `RegexMatchingDict` is working, thank you. I was returning `self(...)` instead.

Comment: `self` is an instance of the class, not the class itself, which is why that didn't work.

Comment: That could be very confusing if you do `val = CustomDict["key"]; print(val["key"])"`. I wouldn't create objects on the fly in `__getitem__` to retrun something different than what is stored in the actual mapping.

Comment: I did say in a comment that subclassing `dict` was likely to be a lot of work to get right.

Comment: Fair enough but I think what you are suggesting is breaking the very principle of a mapping which is to have a set of **unique** key-values pair. No offence, the OP seems happy with your solution!

Comment: @JacquesGaudin A copywriter's adage says that nothing will kill a bad product quicker than good advertising. In the same way, working with a crisp implementation of an unsound idea may turn out to have more value than advice to desist, however correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your second level dictionary is a **normal** `dict` and therefore doesn't use your custom `__getitem__` method.

The code below shows what should be done to have an internal custom `dict`:

```
sec_level_dict = {"KEY": "{ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}"}

sec_level_custom_dict = RegexMatchingDict(sec_level_dict, r"((.*({(.+)}).*))", 4 ,3)

dictionary = {"KEY": sec_level_custom_dict}
custom_dict = RegexMatchingDict(dictionary, r"((.*({(.+)}).*))", 4 ,3)
print(custom_dict["KEY"]["KEY"])
```

If you want to automate this and transform all nested `dict` in custom `dict`, you can customize `__setitem__` following this pattern:

```
class CustomDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, dct):
        super().__init__()
        for k, v in dct.items():
            self[k] = v

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        print("Dictionary:", self, "key:", key, "value:", value)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, self.__class__(value))
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

a = CustomDict({'k': {'k': "This is my nested value"}})

print(a['k']['k'])
```

Comment: Yes, I know what happens. Don't know how to fix it. I want to have this in a dynamic way from inside `__getitem__` (i.e., for any level of indexing).